How to measure the register bandwidth of an NVIDIA GPU?
I want to test the register bandwidth of an NVIDIA GPU (OpenCL/CUDA). How to do that？
I can't find any information about the register bandwidth test on the Internet, only the bandwidth test of the cache at all levels.

Registers have 0 clock cycle access latency and are bound to the GPU core clock frequency.
Say a GPU has 10 TFlops/s compute throughput with FP32 fused-multiply-add instructions. Each FMA instruction does 2 Flops, loads 3 FP32 inputs from registers and writes 1 FP32 output in registers. Each FP32 number is 4 Bytes. That makes 5 Trillion FMA calls per second, accessing 20 Trillion FP32 numbers per second, with a combined register bandwidth of 80TB/s.
So GPU register bandwidth is (TFlops/s for FP32) × (8 Byte/Flop). This is valid for all GPUs.
The FP32 TFlops/s you can measure for example with this OpenCL-Benchmark tool.

ok,thank you!  I did some experiments, and the results are exactly the same as you said. This conclusion is very helpful. Is this conclusion from a paper or a NVIDIA document? I'm a bit curious if this is the official data released by Nvidia, as I haven't found any relevant information before.

@Shui_ you can find the details in Nvidia PTX ISA: https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#floating-point-instructions-fma The fma instruction is universal across GPUs also from other vendors, so my confusion also applies for AMD/Intel GPUs.
